# How to prepare my 1960s home for the EV future

Tags: electrical

My house was built in 1961 and has 100 amp service. 1500sqft. Furnace, tankless WH, dryer, and range are gas, AC is electric. There’s a single 30A 220 circuit in the garage. My panel has one unused 40A/200 circuit which used to be for an electric range. Not counting that, there are 190A worth of circuits (no, I did not double-count the 110v stuff), but my 30A generator handles our normal usage without issue during power outages.

In the next 2-3 years, we will be adding on a ~500sqft master suite which will require at least a few additional circuits, so I’m expecting this project to include an electrical overhaul.

In 5-10 years, I expect we’ll buy our first and possibly second EV, and I’d like to be able to charge both in the garage with the speed and efficiency of a Level 2 (220v) charger. Today’s fastest L2 home chargers are 19.2kw / 80A, requiring a 100A circuit.

I’d like to add solar power and a smallish battery backup eventually. More vehicles are starting to support V2I (vehicle-to-infrastructure — powering the home from the car’s battery during a power outage), and I’d like to be prepared for that as well.

I also want to build a detached garage/workshop someday, which would have things like a lift, a welder, tons of lights, HVAC, etc. At least 500sqft, hopefully more (if I can convince my wife to let me build that big). Probably another EV charger, too. So I figure that’s going to need at least another 200A.

It’s super early, and I’ll definitely employ the services of pros for all of this, so right now I’m just trying to set my own expectations.

So I think I’m going to need 400A service for the home and workshop combined (I’m expecting the load calculation to turn up a number around 225-250, and assuming I’d have to round up to 400). From what research I’ve done so far, >200A residential service is pretty rare, and the equipment is pretty expensive. It would be my preference not to have the house hard wired into separate panels where only one is covered by backup power (although it would be okay if the EV chargers were an exception to that).

Due to trees, the garage building will be better positioned for solar on the roof than the house is. I’d love it if the panels and backup battery on/in the workshop could serve the house when there’s an outage.

#### So, questions:

1. When I call the utility company and ask to be upgraded to 600A service, are they going to call me crazy? Should I expect the detached garage to get a separate service with its own account with the utility company, with 400A service to the house and 200A to the garage? I assume that would undermine the garage-as-solar-backup plan.
2. How likely is it that, during the retrofit, my current main panel can just become a subpanel and continue serving the circuits it already has? The addition (which, conveniently, will be on the side where service comes in) would get its own main panel with a few small circuits for the master suite plus a large branch off to the existing 100A and a couple to the (existing, attached) garage for EV chargers?
3. Are there other significant considerations I should plan for to make all of this work? Will I need an electrical contractor with a particular expertise or certification (beyond what any normal home EC would have) to handle everything?

#### EDIT:

In response to some of the early comments and answers, I want to add a few clarifications:

1. I recognize now that I was being silly, adding up all the loads and assuming I’d need that much service. Clearly I don’t need 600A! I do, however, think there’s a decent chance I’ll need >200 at the end of the story. I’ve edited above accordingly.
2. I know I don’t and won’t *need* 19.2kW charging at home. But I want it! While my home electrical system is already being overhauled, I figure I might as well plan for it.
3. I also don’t need a Porsche Taycan GTS Sport Turismo or a Lucid Air Grand Touring, but those are the EVs that currently have my attention. Both support 80A L2 charging, providing about 75 miles of range in an hour.
4. I work from home; my wife is a stay-at-home mom. Our driving is highly irregular and atypical, with ~weekly instances where we drive for hundreds of miles in one day, then drive almost not at all for the rest of the week.  Most of our driving is to visit family amd friends, go on ski trips, etc — generally at least 100 miles away. Double that for the round trip, then double it again because sometimes we make two such trips in a single day. That’s happened three times in the last month or so (it’s less common outside the holiday season, but it does still happen), and to pull that off with an EV comfortably, some charging while we’re at home between trips would be super helpful (although a stop at an L3 station would likely make sense, we don’t have many of those in my area, and the ones we do have so far are either Tesla-exclusive or pretty far out of the way of our typical routes).
5. I can’t think of a scenario where we’d be doing that with *both cars* on the same day, so if I can have a single 100A circuit that can charge either car at the full 80A (and support having both plugged in at the same time so that the system can charge selectively / intelligently), then I’m on board with only needing one 100A circuit.
6. In Europe, 22kW home chargers have started to spring up. I assume it’s only a matter of time before we have comparable options here. Not everybody needs them, but these products exist for a reason! The public’s EV range anxiety will improve greatly as charging speeds increase, and I think supporting companies who are pushing in that direction by buying that sort of equipment can only help. Even at 80A, charging is nowhere close to the rate of range replenishment we’re all used to with gasoline.
7. I’m aware that ICE cars are better suited for this use case. I have and will continue to have some of those for the foreseeable future (we currently have five cars), but I am trying to push my household in a greener direction. I have enough money to make some pretty nonstandard choices if doing so helps the environment, benefits the grid, and improves my family’s quality of life.

#### EDIT 2: additional clarifications.

1. I accept and acknowledge that what I'm asking for here in terms of EV charging is a luxury, and that it is not strictly necessary. It is nonetheless what I want! Reasonably fast at-home EV charging will provide significant quality-of-life improvements for me and my family, and I'm willing to spend relatively large sums of money to acquire it.
2. I did not intend for the question or the answers to be so heavily focused on the EV parts; rather I'm focused on the coming upgrades to my home electrical system and just wanted to be clear about the demands I want it to satisfy.

When the master suite addition project begins in a couple years, there's going to be some electrical retrofitting. At minimum, this is going to involve excavation of buried lines below a concrete foundation underneath finished interior space, plus the purchase of some relatively expensive equipment. My hope is that, in this phase of the project, we can do some preparation which will simplify the later phases. When I later add the workshop, solar, battery backup, and bidirectional EV charger(s), I don't want to have to rip and replace the the floor again, nor replace any major components I just added a couple years earlier.

I know I'll need a new main panel, and we'll run a branch from there to the current main, and another to the attached garage for faster, hardwired+bidirectional EV charging and the freedom to use the 30A garage outlet for other stuff.

If/when I add a battery backup, I expect it will live in the same room as the new panel (a utility room which we're adding below the master suite, along with a new home office for me and a storage room), so I am reasonably confident I don't need to do much to accommodate it, other than ensure that I have enough space.

I'm thinking that while the foundation is excavated, we can bury some empty PVC in the general direction of the workshop site, route it into the utility room, and cap both ends for now. Then when it's workshop time, excavate the remote end (which would be beyond the foundation boundary), continue from there to the workshop, remove the interior cap, run a feeder, and then connect to the panel. I'm thinking I'd bury three such PVC conduits -- one for the workshop feeder, one for inbound power from the solar panels, and one empty for possible future use. How big should these be?

What else can I do during the master suite phase to prepare for the workshop and/or solar and avoid rework?

Are there notable rules about routing high-amperage lines through walls and ceilings? For conversation, let's assume I'm running one 100A line from the new panel to the EVSE in the attached garage, which is on the opposite end of the house, some 40' away. Do high-amperage lines (I'm assuming this would be 3AWG THHN) have routing requirements or limitations beyond those which appy to standard yellow and orange Romex? Any limits on proximity to copper water lines, gas lines (black pipe), HVAC ducting, etc? I'm trying to determine just how many walls we'll be ripping into, as my house was finished with plaster rather than drywall, so patching is less straightforward than what's typical.

It occurs to me that I would also like to add some additional outlets and lighting in the attached garage, so maybe I should be adding a garage subpanel, and then wire the EVSE(s) from there? That'd mean the subpanel would need >100A from the main (if you accept that I want 80A charging). How big should I go?

Comment: You are probably over sizing everything.  Right now the numbers on your breakers add up 190, but you only have 100 amp service, and probably only top out with using 20 to 40 amps with everything on.  Unless you are driving 30 minutes out of every hour of the day, then 20 or 30 amp charger will be plenty to charge EVs over night.  A common 200 amp service will probably be more than enough for the house and garage/shop unless you are planning industrial usage.  One person can usually just use one tool at a time.

Comment: Most (all?) Level 2 EV chargers, the most powerful you can currently get put into a home, only require a dedicated 40 amp circuit.  So two Level 2 chargers = two 40 amp circuits.  These, along with everything else you mentioned, should fit fine in a standard 200 A panel.

Comment: 80A is absurd overkill for home charging. That's "recharge a 100kWh battery in 5 hours" levels of power. Do you drive 250-400 miles every single day? a 20A / 240V circuit can replenish 150 miles in 14 hours, which is *more* than enough to handle most people's commutes.

Comment: Unless you are going to be running a full time welding service out of your garage with a dozen employees, you aren't going to need 600A service, you probably won't even need 400.

Comment: Who do you have for an electric utility?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I have Consumers Energy.

Comment: @SteveSh 19.2kW L2 chargers are becoming more and more common. They require a 100A circuit and would draw 80A each if both cars are charging. It would be relatively infrequent that I would ever actually use both at full speed at any given moment.

Comment: @crip659 (and whatsisname), thanks — I was somehow missing the fact that I have 190A worth of breakers but can run the house on a 30A generator — which obviously means I can continue to undersize accordingly. ‍♂️

Comment: That said, I think doing that (at least at the same ratio) with the EV chargers might be foolish. There’s strong odds of an honest 160A draw between the two of them actually happening on occasion, and I’d prefer to do that without blowing the main. Is 250A residential service a thing? 200 feels like it would not leave much headroom. Both cars charging, and the well pump happens to kick on while we’re using the toaster….

Comment: @JakeRobb -- is your existing service overhead or underground?

Comment: @SteveSh Level 2 is settable anywhere from 15A to 100A breaker (actual charge being 80% of that).  **It should be sized appropriate to the house's available power**.  40A is a popular one (because the free travel EVSEs meant for use *on the road* come with 50A RV plugs for use at RV parks *on the road*, and 50A sockets are legal on 40A circuits, so they must use 40A. But the travel EVSEs can work at 15A, 20A or 30A also with a different plug dongle.)

Comment: And as far as dual EV charging, one should never install individual units that don't talk to each other.  They should always be using Share2 type power sharing, so the two EVSEs are sharing a single pool of power.  If you *needed* to replace 400 miles a night between two cars, then you'd allocate 80A for both chargers to share, with each probably having a 60A limit individually.  But this is crazy talk.  If someone thinks they need that, they should review what a "mile" is.  Anyone going anywhere near 200 miles a day (thus needing 40A) *shouldn't be driving an EV*.

Comment: @JakeRobb the rules for undersizing (more breakers than service) are in NEC Article 220.  I'm guessing you haven't seen it :) Given that you had two large loads come off your Load Calc, and an all-gas house, I think you can add all the EV charging you'll ***need*** on the service you have now. And the way smart-panels are coming up, with their demand-side management abilities, you might never need a service upgrade - start welding and the system will suspend the compressor or EV charger or whatever is needed to make room.

Comment: The "160A actual" EV charging would only happen *on occasion*, because the cars will be done charging in minutes lol. However EVs are very heavy loads and need a 125% derate (so 160A becomes 200A). They get no discount* in the Load Calculation so you need full 200A of service *Just For Them*. So you will need 400A - 200A for EV charging and 200A for everything else. (but again this is bonkers).

Comment: @JakeRobb * one other thing about 100A EVSEs... you don't get to pick the speed, that is a hard setting made at installation time.  The EVSE will advertise "80A available" which will cause the car to run at *the absolute maximum* for its onboard charger. 24A for a Nissan Leaf, 32A for many EVs including Model 3 RWD, 48A for most other Teslas etc.  The Lightning or Hummer EV will probably go 80A but it still grossly exceeds their needs.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel overhead. I wish it was underground!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, “Anyone going anywhere near 200 miles a day (thus needing 40A) shouldn't be driving an EV.” — I disagree! Such a person stands to save enormously on fuel by switching to electric. They just need to ensure that they buy something with sufficient range, a convenient L3 station along their commute, a suitable charging situation wherever they park at work, or some combination of those.

Comment: I’ve made some small edits and added a bunch of clarifying points at the end of the question. 

Comment: Think of that kind of edge condition as **travel**. (even if it's in 100mi radius of home).  And DC fast chargers are going to become exponentially more available since everyone knows they are the pinch point in EV adoption.  The fastest go 350kW, which is 15x faster than a 19kW setup, and raises a 100kW pack from 20% to 80% *in 10 minutes*. Alec and AgingWheels did a road trip from Chicago to Florida where they were doing pretty much that. (well the Ioniq5 can't go full 350kW). Indeed, they couldn't run into a store and get back before their car had hit 80%.

Comment: Today, DC fast chargers that offer 350kW are fairly rare, and the ones that do exist are notoriously fickle -- they might work great one day, only manage 100kW another, and then a mere 5kW another. The industry is working to improve, but I live in an area that doesn't get these sorts of things early. I'm guessing it will be 10+ years before 350kW charging (or even 150kW) is as reliable and readily available as regular unleaded gasoline is today.

Comment: As for the travel distinction: for me, travel is not the edge condition. When we're driving at all, it's "travel" probably 90% of the time. We live in a rural area. Most of the nearby gas stations are north, west, or south of us, but our most frequent destinations are to the east, with nothing but farmland for 40+ miles -- so needing to fill up en route takes us a good distance out of the way.

Comment: I admit that I am seeking a luxury here: I want to be able to charge at home, relatively quickly, because I am confident that a DC fast charger is not going to pop up anywhere along our most frequent routes any time remotely soon.

Comment: What do you really need to prepare your house for an EV future? A roof full of solar cells, because there's no way the grid can handle an EV future, especially with no new nuclear plant starts.

Comment: @GlenYates shhhhhhh... don't point at the flaws in the _grand scheme_.

Comment: "we can bury some empty PVC" While you're already excavating is an _excellent_ time to do so! Make sure that it's PVC _conduit_ (the grey stuff), not PVC _DWV_ pipe (the white stuff). You can't use DWV for electrical conduit (and pass inspection). As to size, well, take a look at the tables for conduit fill and calculate how big a pipe you'll need for 4 wires (2 hot, neutral, ground) at the expected size to not exceed conduit fill rules. Then go 1/2" bigger, just in case. It'll cost a bit more now, but a lot less than having to dig it up & relay the conduit in the future.

Comment: @FreeMan, thanks for the pipe vs conduit clarification.

Comment: @FreeMan thanks also for the term "conduit fill table," which allowed me to google and find what I wanted. Looks like 2-1/2" or maybe even 3" will be the answer. I'll plan to leave some pull string in the conduit at the time as well.

Comment: You're welcome on both counts, and yes, leaving a _rope_ in all conduit is another _excellent_ idea. Even #4 AL wire is pretty heavy duty stuff and needs something more sturdy than "string". Of course, a "string" can be used to pull a heavier rope through, or an electrician will run a "mouse" through to get his pull cord of choice through.

Comment: I'm preparing for the hydrogen fuel cell future.

Comment: Most of the pull string I'm finding is rated for 210lbs, but I'm seeing some (looks more like nylon webbing than string) rated for 1250lbs. I'd surely hope that's enough? With that much force I'd be worried about breaking something, and I'd suggest that a combination of lubrication and somebody feeding the cable in one end while somebody else pulls at the other should be employed.

Comment: VTC: Way too many questions for one post. Much of it is inviting speculation or opinion-based answers.

Comment: @JakeRobb -- one more service question: given that you're out in the sticks, does your existing service come directly to a meter on the house, or does it come to a meter on a pole in the middle of the yard (called a "maypole" service in some places) instead?

Comment: For all the clown comments let’s just take a simple thing and find out what is the largest residential service??? 400a ! Can your residential transformer feeder even handle a 4x upsize? Get ready for a huge bill as most homes built in this era were 60-100 amp , ask 1 question at a time and you might get an answer, agree with VTC

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel the meter is on the house.

Comment: Well, the question’s closed. Oh well. I got some good and useful comments answers anyway. Thanks everyone! 

FWIW, I think the only reason it feels so unfocused is because I had to explain myself three times to direct the answers away from “you don’t need a fast EV charger.”

Answer (score 16):

### By the EVs today.  Use the 30A+DC fast charging.

In light of your added info, I'd say go right ahead and buy the EVs. The 30A socket already in your garage can feed a dual EVSE that will be plenty for all your ordinary use.

You toss out a hypothetical of multiple sequential days of extremely high mileage. OK, **treat that like it's travel** and just hit DC fast chargers. They are fastest between 20% and 80%.  For 800V-architecture cars, they'll run as high as 350kW, which means 20-80% **happens in 10 minutes**. People report they can't even duck into a nearby shop before the car has reached the 80% mark.  That doesn't surprise me one bit. *Note you are already doing this with gas cars*.

Then, with a couple years' practical experience under your belt, you can assess whether a 100A tier EVSE is worth bothering to provision.

In discussion you've figured out that 600A is unnecessary and 400A will definitely suffice. I would suggest that.  In your shoes I myself might try to shimmy it in under 200A, not so hard with emerging demand-side management tech (striking an arc with the welder makes the EVSE slow down momentarily).

### Let's inform expectations about EV charging.

> Today’s fastest L2 home chargers are 19.2kw / 80A, requiring a 100A circuit.

This is a common misconception and a big barrier to EV adoption - people thinking they need huge power to have an EV. They really don't.

Technology Connections has a fantastic "beginner's guide to EV charging" - Alec is *so* knowledgeable that the snarky humor is well worth it - 99% right* and I've been into EVs since before Alec was born.  28:15 is the snap answer to "do I need a big charger" and 32:55 even more vividly.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iyp_X3mwE1w.

Like I say above, to "dip your toe in EVs" just use the 30A circuit you have to feed two cars using "Share2 style" Power Sharing EVSE's such as Grizzl-E Duo. $900 and you're done, don't even need an electrician.  From what I can see, you have room in your NEC Article 220 Load Calculation to do that.  You could do the same with two Tesla Wall Connectors but you'll need to hardwire them.

* I don't agree with Alec's love of plugs and sockets. I think EVSEs should be hardwired if at all possible, to sidestep the NEC 2020 requirement for costly GFCI on sockets.  Hardwired EVSEs never need GFCI because **they are** GFCIs.

### With 30A for EVs, let's revisit that Load Calculation

I'm kidding. Once your 400A service goes in, you can bump the EVs to anything you want within reason.

> I also want to build a detached garage/workshop someday, which would have things like a lift, a welder, tons of lights, HVAC, etc. At least 500sqft, hopefully more (if I can convince my wife to let me build that big). Probably another EV charger, too. So I figure that’s going to need at least another 200A.

You'll want to be doing all the EV charging reasonably near each other, to accommodate the Power Sharing interconnect cabling.

The way these loads are figured out is a NEC Article 220 Load Calculation. That's an engineer-approved and time-tested procedure for not overloading panels. Lighting and socket loads get tossed into a "catch-all" (3 VA per square foot of house). Kitchen and laundry 120V circuits get 1500 VA each. Hard-wired or fastened-in-place appliances get various favorable "discounts" due to intermittent use.

Welders and ranges get a *huge* discount because they run a lightweight duty cycle - you're a hobby welder, you're not continuously fabricating pipe.

EVs get no discount at all because they are hard continuous loads. They must be provisioned for 125% of actual (hence 48A on a 60A circuit) and that counts at full value on the Load Calculation.

> So I think I’m going to need 600A service for the home and garage combined. From what research I’ve done so far, >200A residential service is pretty rare (400A not unheard of), and the equipment is pretty expensive.

I do not foresee any way that 400A would not meet your needs, even if you have two EVs sharing 100A.  I could probably squeeze all your stuff into 200A, but you know I have different sensibility about EV "needs".

And newer heat pump are ridiculously efficient (they have 38 SEER units now; that's 11 units of heat moved per 1 unit of electricity spent, at least in the cooling direction; heat pumping isn't quite there, but it does run cold-weather).  Add a Williams/Empire "no electricity needed" wall furnace for "electricity out" heat, and you're in good shape.

400A is perfectly common, and widely used on homes with *older* heat pumps that needed emergency heat, as much as 140A for a friend in Indiana. To save costs, 400A is implemented as dual 200A main breakers. These days, the 2 breakers will be in either a "Meter-Main" or a "Ranch Panel" (meter-main + a few breaker spaces for well house, barn, shop etc.) Certainly under $1000 for the service equipment + main breakers.

> a couple to the garage for EV chargers?

You can't have more than one feeder to a detached outbuilding.  So you will need to run one feeder to the garage, have a subpanel there, and then all garage loads fed off that subpanel.

### Backup power

> It would be my preference not to have the house hard wired into separate panels where only one is covered by backup power (although it would be okay if the EV chargers were an exception to that).

Cost of the transfer equipment is the reason people like to bunch the "to be on backup power" loads into one 200A or 100A panel.  But that's really your call.

Note that "on backup power" is a happy exception to the "one feeder per outbuilding" rule.  So you can have a non-backup feeder and a backup power feeder.

> When I call the utility company and ask to be upgraded to 600A service, are they going to call me crazy? Should I expect the detached garage to get a separate service with its own account with the utility company, with 400A service to the house and 200A to the garage? I assume that would undermine the garage-as-solar-backup plan.

Yes, separate services would destroy your ability to use the garage as a site for batteries to back up the house. Can't have multiple services criss-crossing between buildings.

The power company has to look at their own transformers and see if they can deliver you that much service.  If not, the price may reflect a transformer upgrade, or they may simply say "no".  But usually, they're happy to take your money.

> How likely is it that, during the retrofit, my current main panel can just become a subpanel and continue serving the circuits it already has?

Sure, that's fine.

> Due to trees, the garage building will be better positioned for solar on the roof than the house is. I’d love it if the panels and backup battery on the garage couple serve the house when there’s an outage.

That's not a problem, and it might actually comprise *a third* allowable feeder between house and garage. Or not; the technology here is moving pretty fast.

I am no fan of *rooftop* solar.  A roof has **one job** (actually two if you count giving firemen access to your building's bones so they can extinguish a fire there). Solar impedes both jobs. I prefer free-standing solar arrays supported by a simple structure that serves as a shade structure and not a proper roof.   Good places for that are over parking spots, patios, pool or driveway.

The nut of the problem is firemen need to climb on your roof to fight fires. They can't be electrocuted by the solar, *which can't be turned off* remember. They must have "Rapid Shutdown" meaning they throw a switch and the solar segments into sections with safe voltages (if it's DC).  With AC microinverters, that just happens automatically, which is why microinverters are popular.

Problem is, you want the solar to work during grid-down times via a battery. Microinverters greatly complicate that, forcing you into more expensive solutions e.g. a full commercial Tesla Powerwall system.

> Are there other significant considerations I should plan for to make all of this work? Will I need an electrical contractor with a particular expertise or certification (beyond what any normal home EC would have) to handle everything?

The hard part will be the home power/battery. I would seek out a specialist who does this type of system regularly.  A general electrician is going to treat this as a "learn as they go" deal, and will tend to try to sell you everything they can, and won't help you simplify.

And especially be aware of the "solar mills" who are basically out to sell your name to solar installers, who want to stamp out cookie-cutter "every one the same" solar systems as fast as possible to chase subsidy money. They don't want to be tangled up in complex and custom systems. You mustn't let yourself be placed in a "Sales Funnel", you must be very forward about reaching out to installers, and be picky and ask them for examples of systems they have done.

Comment: Harper, I always love your riffs on this answer. One quick thing: micro-inverter systems can work with the same external AC disconnect that the house should already have. Grid goes away, micro inverters shut down, and there you are, the system is totally safe.

Comment: I would suggest you to add something along the lines of "it's advised to enable subtitles and put the playback speed to 2x in order to make the video more easier to listen to". Alec makes good videos but he talks real slow and makes jokes a lot which the people I suggested to watch not care much.

Comment: @KMJ yes, except OP also wants the solar to work *during grid-down*.  And microinverter is useless for that.   Well, asterisk, *if cost is no object* you can acquire a **grid-forming inverter** like the Tesla PowerWall which will trick the microinverters into powering back up.  However, that forces you into their "ecosystem" with *their* ATS, *their* batteries etc, which drives cost into the stratosphere.  With DC panels you can feed your own battery with your own MPPT charge controller etc.

Comment: @DeltaOscarUniform I'd love to find a more accessible source for the info. Also it seems slow *only because we already know it*.  EVs contain a lot of concepts, and also a lot of EVers hold wrong beliefs they must be talked out of.

Comment: Noting that Technology Connections has its own ecosystem of connecting knowledge, such as "how an EVSE works", "road trip experience" etc.  That plus the million+ subscribers makes Alec a trusted authority. I could make videos on the same topic but with 3 subscribers I'd just be a madman shouting into the wind.

Comment: If the rooftop solar were mounted on a stand such that the underside remains accessible, how much does that alleviate your concerns? All of the places on my property you described are well shaded by several huge maple trees, and I’d prefer not to give up more lan space than the workshop itself will consume. Maybe the panels could be mounted on the workshop’s exterior walls, acting as a sort of awning/soffit along the sides….

Comment: Thank you for the well considered and thorough answer!! Any advice on how to find/select the specialist electrician? Is there some sort of training or certification they’d have, keywords I should search for?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Enphase makes a battery setup that works with their microinverters including for backup power usage. Of course you have to go in to their ecosystem but it works.

Comment: @JakeRobb the issue is whether firemen will have to work around the panels to fight a fire on the structure. If the're going to be up there swinging pick axes, then the solar system must have Rapid Shutdown to render the panels to safe voltages.  This complicates and raises the cost for the battery system you seek, forcing you into top tier stuff like Tesla or Enphase where they want top shelf transfer switches and *their* batteries. If cost is no object, then disregard my concern.  I tend to write answers that spend your money like it's *my* money lol. Any fool can tell you to buy Apple.

Comment: On finding an electrician, that's a tough one because there are *so, so many people "marketing solar" and their business is basically "lead generation" to sell your name to quick-n-dirty solar installers who just slap in the same cookie cutter systems. Those people won't want to deviate from their standard recipe.  I would ask them for 10 examples of battery/solar systems they have built.

Comment: While I take umbridge at the implication that I'm a fool (there are more Apple devices in this house than I care to count), an option in which I trade money (of which I have plenty) for a fully integrated system is one that would have a lot of appeal for me. Anything Tesla is a hard no, but Enphase stuff looks nice. Not saying I'd go that direction for sure; I'd want to look at all options.

Comment: In your last sentence, "I would be outbound about reaching out to installers," you say "outbound". [I do not think that word means what you think it means](https://youtu.be/YIP6EwqMEoE). :)

Comment: "[Buy] the EVs today." Ha, no. Today is not the right time for me to buy for several reasons not relevant here. It'll likely be 5-10 years like I said. :)

Comment: @JakeRobb  then I called myself a fool too, as this was written on a Mac :)  No, what I was saying is that consultants feel very safe recommending vertically integrated turnkey solutions, but they disregard their absurd cost. (sort of like Apple RAM... $200 per 8GB, nope.) Which can either put the project out of reach financially, or force compromises which causes the project to fail its mission.

Comment: @FreeMan OK edited.

Comment: Better, thanks. I wasn't sure quite what you meant, or I'd have fixed it myself. You know I'm not shy that way... :)

Answer (score 4):

> It would be my preference not to have the house hard wired into separate panels where only one is covered by backup power

Well. If you don't separate backup circuits you'll probably end up with a generator and extension cords.

Solar is great (I put 10kWp on my roof) but it has one big issue: it doesn't work if there's no sun. So, if the installation is sized properly for backup use:

- In winter, during those grey dark days when the sun barely shines, production is simply ridiculous: sometimes I get 100-200W out of the 10kWp panels. I  got a week of bad weather recently, so I could really test it: it managed to power the two freezers, but anything more would have been a stretch.
- It will be way overdesigned for the summer, and will produce a lot more energy than you can use, so you get free air conditioning, free hot water, some people even heat their swimming pool with "free" solar electricity. If you have enough batteries, they will also nuke your electricity bill at night. If your utility wants to buy the extra power you produce, it can be an option, but make sure to read the fine print.
- In spring and autumn, it should produce enough to zero out your electricity bill.

However these savings have to be balanced against the high cost of an overdesigned installation. If the goal is to pay less electricity bills, the installation can be smaller, and therefore cheaper, than if the goal is backup. Unless you sell it, excess energy production earns nothing.

If the goal is backup, then in order to have enough guaranteed energy to power the loads during the worst days, the installation must be overdesigned and more expensive than it should be. If there is a blackout then you need to have an automatic contactor somewhere that switches between powering the whole house or just powering the critical loads (some inverters simply offer a backup output). This means thinking ahead of time about panels and cable routing so it doesn't become a mess of extension cords. If the solar installation must power the whole house in order to power the freezer, in all weather conditions, then it would need to be absurdly large, in other words you will need a generator. Then, when it runs out of gas, you will end up with extension cords between your solar inverter and your freezer.

In addition, it is not allowed to connect the backup supply and the grid, because that would zap the guy who comes to fix it when the electricity goes down. So you need to think about separate circuits and how to switch them.

Most solar inverters will require a smartmeter or a way to measure how much power the whole house uses, so during the day they can balance between charging batteries and powering the house, and at night they can pull just the right amount of power from batteries to compensate for what the house uses and export it into the grid, to reduce net power measured by the utility meter. So you need more conduits, and a lot of planning. Empty plastic conduits are really cheap, they're a nice way to future-proof an installation.

To use solar power to charge EVs, they must be parked at home during the day, so it is not compatible with all lifestyles.

That was a bit of an information dump, but the gist of it is, integrating solar into an existing installation is quite complicated if you want backup, so planning ahead is essential, and you can't do that if you don't know what you don't know.

Comment: "If you don't separate backup circuits you'll probably end up with a generator and extension cords."

Why? Doesn't it just mean I need a larger transfer switch?

Comment: Because solar won't power the whole house

Comment: It can when paired with enough battery capacity and some discretion. My intention is to have enough battery capacity to power the whole house for a couple hours, and then bidirectional EV power significantly augmenting that (should be good for a couple days at least).

Comment: BTW, when I say "power the whole house," I mean "all circuits energized," not "using every electrical device in the house simultaneously." I just don't want my decision regarding which circuits are backup worthy and which are not to be hardwired. If something isn't backup worthy, I'll just turn it off!

Comment: Okay, for a couple hours it'll work. I meant an actual blackout (several days without power).

Answer (score 3):

Most utilities will only provide one point of service to a residence property so multiple accounts might be out of the question. Plus, the power company won't just upgrade your service to 600 amps. You'll have to get your contractor to install your 600 amp meter center, very expensive, and panels per approved plans and they might be able to use your existing panel. Then the power company will do their own evaluation and provide you with what they think you need. They would increase your service connection as needed in the future. Thinking about it now is fine but you'll need to get with professional designers to draw up the plans and get approvals

There a very great chance you won't need a 600 amp service.